# Access U-SQL execution logs

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-management-api

Can we access U-SQL execution logs? Are these exposed to developers to gather important statistics? Is there any API that is exposed to us or any U-SQL library already present?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ajay, Can you provide some more information about what information you want to programmatically access? Some of the information is available in the location that Saveen explains. If you need other information, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

(Data Lake Team here)

The execution of a U-SQL job produces many files - they are stored in folders in the associated default Data Lake Store

Here's an example of a path to one of the folders

```
/system/jobservice/jobs/Usql/2016/12/30/00/01/6d7dc7f0-c5da-40fe-afed-a6051bf0ca97
```

Having said that, there are some logs that are not placed in that folder and the Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio reads and displays all the information you should need to understand a job.